# Cannot soft reset git repository in the middle of a merge, but there is no merge to abort

Tags: git, merge, reset, conflict, abort

When running the command `git reset --soft HEAD^` in my repository, the terminal tells me it is in the middle of a merge:

```
fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.
```

But when trying to abort the merge with `git merge --abort`, the terminal states that there is no merge:

```
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

Is there a "hidden" merge in git of some sort? I don't know much about how git works and am not sure how to fix this. If I run `git reset --hard HEAD` will the changes I made to the files still be saved and I just have to restage and commit them?

Comment: Please check output of `git status`. It should report any operation in progress.

Comment: Unfortunately I copied the conflicting files to a temporary directory, hard reset, and then re added the files for commiting before I saw this comment. Thank you anyway, I realised that would have helped.

Answer (score 26):

Partial answer: you'll lose all the changes you made while running git reset --hard

Comment: Damn well thanks for that. I would give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Oh, that saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What I was looking for was to abort the merge and return to the previous state:

```
git reset --merge
```

After that I could checkout a different branch, stash, or do a soft reset like normal.

Comment: quite a bad suggestion - I lost my changes =/

Answer (score 0):

You might have merge conflicts. If you resolve your conflicts, the run `git rebase --continue`, then the soft reset option should be available.

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` your changes and then `git reset --soft HEAD^` before running `git stash pop` to get back your old changes